# Populating a HTML form with saved values for testing

Tags: html, unit-testing

Does anyone know of a browser plugin or application that will save form values then populate the same form when required?

Let me explain what I mean. I'm currently working on the registration page of a web application. As you can imagine it's quite long and I have to keep filling it out. I can fill it out reasonably quickly using values already entered by tabbing through the fields and hitting the down arrow. But, it's not fast enough! Ideally I'd like to enter the form values, then somehow save all the values under a name. E.g. "Valid registration". When I come back to the page I'd like to select my saved "Valid registration" form values and have the whole form populated automatically.

I've tried things like [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) but they are no good, they don't populate a form with valid data.

EDIT

I've also looked at [autofill forms](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autofill-forms/) which is better, but still requires a lot of set up for a long form containing non standard fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague pointed out that you can use Selenium IDE for this purpose. It's not really what it's intended for but it works like a charm.

Simply record yourself entering some details on the form, save it as something meaningful (e.g. "RegistrationValid" or "RegistrationInvalidPostcode") then you can run it whenever you like to auto populate the form. The only negative point is that the plugin is Firefox only.

You can download the plugin here: http://seleniumhq.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

hi this is Rahul Mandaliya.

some time ago i had faced that problem , and i got the answer , i used RoboFill software for store some data like user name , password and other .

i think you have to download this software.

i have put link for Download is : http://www.roboform.com/dist/RoboForm-Setup.exe

if did not get this software from above link , you have to manually go to www.roboform.com and Download this software.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've checked out the software and it's not quite what I'm looking for. Ideally I'd like some software that just saved the form fields I've entered directly from the form rather than having to enter the fields again into the software